# Ejemplo básico de compras integrada, Pagos InApp en Android

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, pago-in-app

Me estoy mirando la documentación oficial de [Facturación integrada](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) quiero permitir al usuario que pueda adquirir una versión completa con todas las funcionalidades acitvadas a partir de la actual `gratuita` pero limitada.

Pero no acabo de encontrar nada, que me sea de guia en su implementación, partiendo de un proyecto limpio generado con `Android-Studio`.

**Lo que llevo realizado:**

La instalación: Siguiendo los pasos de [Cómo implementar facturación integrada](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html?hl=es-419) cuando se instale el `IInAppBillingService.aidl` necesario hacer `rebuild`

**Lo que me falta**

Para que la pregunta no sea consolidara demasiado extensa, aclaro los puntos.

- Al pulsar botón comprar, que abre el diálogo de facturación.
- Control base, detectar si la compra ha sido realizada con éxito, error...
- Controlador de bandera para determinar si está activada, tener toda la features `full-version` o tener que mostrar nuevamente el dialogo de compra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iré actualizando la respuesta, mientras vaya descubriendo y configurando.

### Instalación de AppBillingService

La instalación: Siguiendo los pasos de [Cómo implementar facturación integrada](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html?hl=es-419) cuando se instale el IInAppBillingService.aidl necesario hacer rebuild

Descargar `IabHelper` y derivados del [Ejemplo de Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing)
No ser porque da error

> getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus is not available in Google Play Billing
>   Library r5

Archivo modificado para que no de error [update IabHelper](https://github.com/lomza/IabHelper/blob/master/IabHelper.java)

El sistema del ejemplo es obtener la versión PREMIUM, a partir de la gratuita.

Se debe especificar la compra integrada con un identificador, en este caso `premium` eso se hace en el `Google Play Developer Console` siguiendo [Administrar la facturación integrada](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html?hl=es-419)

#### PREREQUISITOS

```
private IabHelper mHelper;
private IabBroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;
private IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener;
boolean mIsPremium = false;
static final String SKU_PREMIUM = "premium";
static final int RC_REQUEST = 10001;
private IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener;
```

La actividad añadir la implementación `IabBroadcastReceiver.IabBroadcastListener`

Al `onCreate` iniciar las compras integradas.

```
String base64EncodedPublicKey = "TU_CLAVE_APP"
mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
```

Habilitar el sistema de depuración

```
mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true); //quitarlo si es modo release
```

#### Iniciar el sistema de pagos integrados

Se inicia el servicio, para obtener las compras integradas, para luego obtener el listado de items comprados con otro listener `mGotInventoryListener`

```
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting setup.");
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + result);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
            }

            if (mHelper == null) return;

            mBroadcastReceiver = new IabBroadcastReceiver((IabBroadcastReceiver.IabBroadcastListener) MainActivity.this);
            IntentFilter broadcastFilter = new IntentFilter(IabBroadcastReceiver.ACTION);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, broadcastFilter);

            // IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
            try {
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
            } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
                complain("Error querying inventory. Another async operation in progress.");
            }
        }
    });
```

### Obtener el inventario

Con el listener `QueryInventoryFinishedListener` se puede recuperar los objetos del inventario de compra, así poder activar el flag `mIsPremium` de la app para que tenga toda las funcionalidades.

```
    mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");

            // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
            if (mHelper == null) return;

            // Is it a failure?
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
                return;
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "QUERY inventory was successful.");


            // Do we have the premium upgrade?
            Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM);
            mIsPremium = (premiumPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(premiumPurchase));
            Log.d("PREMIUM =","User is " + (mIsPremium ? "PREMIUM" : "NOT PREMIUM"));
            alert("User is " + (mIsPremium ? "PREMIUM" : "NOT PREMIUM"));

            Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
        }
    };
```

### Realizar compra PREMIUM

Con `launchPurchaseFlow` se lanzará el cuadro de dialogo donde el usuario puede ver el precio del item y escoger su forma de pago.

```
String payload = "mypurchasetoken";

try {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(MainActivity.this, SKU_PREMIUM, RC_REQUEST,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
} catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

### Capturando el evento de Compra

La compra puede retornar diferentes errores:

- cancelación parte de usuario
- pago rechazado
- compra realizada

Para capturar el evento de compra se usa `OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener`

```
mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);

        // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (result.isFailure()) {
                if (result.getResponse() == 7) {
                    complain("Ya tiene el producto ");
                } else {
                    complain("Error purchasing: " + result);
                }
            return;
        }
        if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
            complain("Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
            return;
        }

        Log.w(TAG, "Purchase successful.");

        if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_PREMIUM)) {
            // bought the premium upgrade!
            Log.w(TAG, "Purchase is premium upgrade. Congratulating user.");
            alert("Thank you for upgrading to premium!");
            mIsPremium = true;
        }
    }
};
```

**Update**

## Usando librería Android In-App Billing v3 Library

Recomiendo la librería [In-App Billing v3 Library](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) que facilita todo el proceso de preparativos y hace que usar los pagos sea de lo más intuitivo, agilizando comprobaciones etc...